# Chaining Apex calls from Lightning Component within Promises doesn't reset the Salesforce CPU time limit countdown?

Tags: promise, salesforce, cpu, apex, salesforce-lightning

because of the CPU time limit, I'm chaining several Apex calls from an Aura Lightning component using JS promises, hoping that comming back on Front side would end the transaction and reset the CPU time limit countdown.
But it is not the case.
Is this supposed to not work ?
And do you have any idea how to actually reset the Apex CPU time limit ?

Thanks :)

Comment: This is most likely caused by boxcarring, you can do some reading here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/263382/how-to-turn-boxcarring-off-for-lwc-imperative-apex-method-calls

Comment: @zaitsman Precisely! Good to know, thanks. We ended up manipulating the page just a bit between critical calls (switching a display of nothing ON and OFF). That seems to truely complete the transactions and enforce the synchronicity (and unicity) of the multiple Apex calls (still around 10 seconds of loading for the page but it should be slightly better in a production org).